# Angular 2 review system : implementing the replays

Tags: javascript, angular

In my Angular 2 application I display a list of component like this (after doing *ngFor) :

**app.component.html**

```
<my-example-component></my-example-component> // 1
<my-example-component></my-example-component> // 2
<my-example-component></my-example-component> // 3
<my-example-component></my-example-component> // 4
<my-example-component></my-example-component> // 5
```

**my-example.component.html :**

```
<h1>{{title}}</h1> // juste as example
......
<button>Click ME</button>
```

What I would like do to do is when I click on the 'click me' button in myExample component, I would like to display another component (a text area). Just below the given myExample component that I click on.

**EDIT**

This is for a review system, and the component I want to display below the myexampleComponent (which is a single review) is a replay to that review.

Answer (score 1):

**DEMO** : ***https://plnkr.co/edit/NzVUHpT7WQWPB2mmUlJM?p=preview***

You should use **`componentFactoryResolver`** to add **`(component)`** dynamically from **`myexamplecomponent`**

```
/*-----------comment Component start--------*/
@Component({
  selector: 'comment',
  template: `<textarea cols="20" rows="5">Hi</textarea>`
})
export class comment{}

/*-----------comment Component end--------*/

/*-----------my-example-component Component start--------*/
@Component({
  selector: 'my-example-component',
  entryComponents: [comment],
  template: `<div #target> Child {{n}}
      <button (click)="clickMe()">Add Comment</button>
  </div>`
})

export class MyExampleComponent{
  @Input() n: number;

  @ViewChild('target', {read: ViewContainerRef}) target: ViewContainerRef;
  cmpRef: ComponentRef<comment>;
  private isViewInitialized:boolean = false;

  constructor(private componentFactoryResolver: ComponentFactoryResolver, private compiler: Compiler,
      private cdRef:ChangeDetectorRef) {}


  clickMe() {
    let factory = this.componentFactoryResolver.resolveComponentFactory(comment, 2);
    this.cmpRef = this.target.createComponent(factory)
    //this.cmpRef.instance.n = 'foobar';
    //this.cdRef.detectChanges();
  }
}

/*-----------my-example-component Component end--------*/
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I would do it:

*define in parent component: `showIndex = null;` and set it back to null when you want to hide it again.*

*parent component view:*

```
<div template="ngFor let item of [1,2,3,4,5]; let i = index;">
<my-example-component (onShowMore)="showIndex = i"></my-example-component>
  <div *ngIf="showIndex === i">More stuff in here</div>
</div>
```

*MyExampleComponent:*

```
@Component({
    selector: 'my-example-component',
    template: `<div style="border: 1px solid salmon"><button (click)="onShowMore.emit(null)">Show More</button></div>`
})

export class MyExampleComponent
{
    @Output() onShowMore = new EventEmitter<any>();
}
```

Edit How to toggle stuff in child component (code not tested):

```
import {Component, Output, EventEmitter, Input} from "@angular/core"

@Component({
    selector: 'Parent',
    template: `<child *ngFor="let item of [1,2,3,4,5]; let i = index;"(onShowMore)="onShowMore($event)" [index]="i" [showIndex]="showIndex"></child>`
})

export class ParentComponent
{
    private showIndex: number | null;

    ngOnInit()
    {
        this.showIndex = null;
    }

    onShowMore(childIndex)
    {
        this.showIndex = childIndex
    }
}


@Component({
    selector: 'child',
    template: `
            <div>
              <button (click)="showIndex === index ? hide() : show()">
                {{showIndex === index ? 'Hide me' : 'Show me'}}
              </button>
            </div>
            <div *ngIf="showIndex === index">This is more content</div>
            `
})

export class ChildComponent
{
    @Input() showIndex: number | null;
    @Input() index: number;
    @Output() onShowMore = new EventEmitter<number | null>();


    show()
    {
        this.onShowMore.emit(this.index);
    }

    hide()
    {
        this.onShowMore.emit(null);
    }
}
```

Comment: the problem is that my comment component is INSIDE my-exampleComponent and not in the parent like you did

Comment: Yeah no problem, was going to say you could just re pass in the 2 index and make the checks inside the child component. Mark as correct if it helped you.